# Ignore fields in jackson I/O serialization and also ignore unknown fields

Tags: java, json, jackson

As i read in the documentation:

```
// (i.e. not include in JSON output; or being set even if they were included)
 \@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "internalId", "secretKey" })
 // To ignore any unknown properties in JSON input without exception:
 \@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
```

but how can I ingore both unknown AND given

Comment: I'm not an expert, but maybe just add two annotations, or you can add only one?

Comment: i can only add one annotation

Comment: JamesB Eclipse don't complain , I think it works

Comment: If you could accept my answer, that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I have understood you correctly, you can combine the conditions you want into the same annotation:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "internalId", "secretKey" }, ignoreUnknown = true)
```